# Проблема с переходом между сценами

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите почему во время перехода с главного меню на игровую сцену главное меню подвисает (самое интересное переход с игровой сцены на игровую сцену происходит мгновенно, а именно г.меню подвисает).
С начала я использовал

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(data.LastScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

потом попробовал

```
AsyncOperation async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(data.LastScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

ничего не изменилось

Comment: "Подвисание" это и есть загрузка сцены

Comment: Можете во время этой самой загрузки загрузить промежуточную сцену с прогресс баром например(гайдов на ютубе полно)

Comment: я хотел подобие прогресс бара сделать в главном меню

Comment: Мой ответ отвечает на ваш вопрос или у вас остались какие-то вопросы?

Answer (score 2):

Даже с `LoadSceneAsync` будет подвисание в редакторе - это особенность его устройства, в билде все должно быть нормально. Обычно подобные вещи делаются через корутины для простоты, но ничего не мешает реализовать это "вручную" через `Update()`.

```
// вместо обычной локальной переменной класса
// можно использовать slider и менять его значение value
float progress;

AsyncOperation asyncOp;

// пример вызова корутины с загрузкой
void LoadLevel(string sceneName){
    StartCoroutine(LoadNewSceneAsync(stringName));
}

// как только сцена загрузится, она не будет автоматически запущена
// чтобы запустить ее - нужно вручную поменять allowSceneActivation c false на true
// что-то вроде задела на "press any key to continue..."
void ActivateScene(){
    asyncOp.allowSceneActivation = true;
}

IEnumerator LoadNewSceneAsync(string sceneName) {
    asyncOp = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);
    asyncOp.allowSceneActiovation = false;
    while(!asyncOp.isDone) {
        // При allowSceneActiovation = false; 
        // максимальное значение async.progress - 0.9f
        progress = asyncOp.progress / 0.9f;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```